# Remove “A” after “Appendix” without removing the numbering

Tags: numbering, appendices

I am using the following code after \appendix:

```
\renewcommand\appendixname{Appendix}
\chapter{}
```

And then my title for my appendix is "Appendix A". How do I remove "A", but still keep the numbering for my equation, my image etc. (for example so the number for my first equation still is A.1)?

I have tried with this one:

```
\renewcommand\thechapter{} 
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}.
```

Then "A" will be removed from the title, which is great. But then the number (A.) for the equations, figures etc. will also be removed, which it should not be.

I am using thesis by the way.

Answer (score 7):

if you want a separate "chapter" title as well as the designation "Appendix",
with some document classes you can set the situation up this way:

```
\appendix
\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\chapter{Title}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A}
```

to establish the desired form and numbering for elements that may be included
in the appendix, add these directions as appropriate.  (not all document classes reset the counters automatically).

```
\setcounter{section}{0}
\setcounter{theorem}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thechapter.\arabic{theorem}}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
```

i don't know for sure whether `thesis` operates this way.

Answer (score 3):

So you only want one chapter in your appendix and you want it to just be called Appendix and not Appendix A? You could use the starred version of chapter. Then redefine `\theequation` to number it the way you want.

```
\chapter*{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{A.\arabic{equation}}
```

If you still want it to appear in your `\tableofcontents` you would need to add it like

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
```

Comment: That works perfect! But how do I also activate the numbering A. for the figure?

Comment: @Jonathan You guys know, that *A* is not the abbreviation for *appendix*, right?

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I am using the danish word _Appendiks_ in my thesis, and then I think it is a fine abbreviation for _Appendiks_ in this case. And the line will be really long if I write for example (appx.1).

Comment: @Johannes_B: I thought `A` stands for `Aftermath` ;-)

Comment: @Jonathan You can have more than one appendix, one with pictures, one with diagrams, one with maps, whatever. The counter is for referencing: See map 2 in Appendix C or see digram 3 in Appendix B.

Comment: The figure caption uses \def\fnum@figure{\figurename\nobreakspace\thefigure} You can renewcommand any of them.

Answer (score -1):

```
\appendix
\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
\chapter{\label{chap:appendix} }
\input{appendix}
```